# data not loading from ajax call all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, asynchronous

I'm currently making calls to a api that returns xml! I'm thinking this is an async issue, i'm trying to figure out why the data i'm receiving back is inconsistent, sometimes i receive some data back but not all, the data loads in when it does at random order it might load the last first, and the 1st might be the last. . . I do not want it to be synchronous however I do want all the data to load. . . I just dont understand why is this loading data when it wants to and not at all times ...i was reading something about promises but its not working at all for me

HTML

```html
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='13435'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='15339'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='14656'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='13447'></div>
<div class='grid-item' data-grid='12243'></div>
```

JS

```js
$(".grid-item").each(function(i) {
  var items = [];
  var prod_id = $(this).attr('data-grid');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'xml',
    data: {
      grid: 'set',
      prod_id: prod_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find('a\\:Inventory').each(function(index, value) {
        var name = $(this).find('Name').html();
        var age = $(this).find('Age').html();

        var display = `
          <div>
            <div class='col-xs-12 text-center no-padding'>
            <div class='col-xs-3 no-padding grid-data-box'>${name} </div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 no-padding grid-data-box'>${age}</div>
          </div>
        `;

        items.push({
          name: name,
          age: age,
        });

        $('[data-grid="'+prod_id+'"]').append(display)  ;
      });

      console.log(items);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes thank you i updated

Comment: Please note your code will execute all requests at the same time, does you PHP allow this, do you get any errors in console.?

Comment: You can use a `console.log(data);` right after your `success: function(data) {` to see what is being returned each time. I would also recommend that your returned xml contain the `prod_id` that it is for, and use that when appending to the document, instead of the global `var prod_id`

Comment: keith after further investigation I am receiving a error from php failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests . . . . some of the request goes thru and others fail , its inconsistent